# Conditionally creating matrix or dataframe in R

Tags: r, combinations, permutation, conditional-formatting, combinatorics

I have two objects let's call them 1 and 2. They can take either 1 or 2 as values for x variable and depending on that, their y values (binary) are determined as depicted in the image.

For example, if x=1 then only yA can be 1. But if x=2, all yA, yB and yC for that object can be 1. The constraint is that for each object maximum one y can be 1. In the image, blue columns are for object 1 and greens are for object 2.

Is there any efficient way to do it as the number of variables in original problem is much higher?

EDIT: The objective is to find all the possible combination of y variables as depicted in the image. The image is only to provide an idea for expected outcome.

[image]

Comment: Please don't provide images of data, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). If you have this in Excel or something similar, save as a CSV and please provide it in a code-block in your question as raw CSV (or format into a frame/matrix in R and use `dput(.)`). Thanks.

Comment: @r2evans This is actually an example of output I am expecting. So it's not really data and answering this question will not require using this table. Should I still provide the CSV file? Thanks

Comment: If the problem is to find any feasible configuration satisfying certain constraints please provide the equations for those constraints using R code and please follow the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag page on asking questions and, in particular if `X` is your data as an R object show the output of `dput(X)` so that others know exactly what you have without guessing or retyping it.  Note that questions must be focused on a specific problem.  Generic questions are normally closed.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a brute-force generation.

First, creating the basic frame of all `y*` columns:

```r
dat <- data.frame(yA=c(1,NA,NA),yB=c(NA,1,NA),yC=c(NA,NA,1),ign=1)
dat <- merge(dat, dat, by="ign")
names(dat)[-1] <- c("y1A", "y1B", "y1C", "y2A", "y2B", "y2C")
dat
#   ign y1A y1B y1C y2A y2B y2C
# 1   1   1  NA  NA   1  NA  NA
# 2   1   1  NA  NA  NA   1  NA
# 3   1   1  NA  NA  NA  NA   1
# 4   1  NA   1  NA   1  NA  NA
# 5   1  NA   1  NA  NA   1  NA
# 6   1  NA   1  NA  NA  NA   1
# 7   1  NA  NA   1   1  NA  NA
# 8   1  NA  NA   1  NA   1  NA
# 9   1  NA  NA   1  NA  NA   1
```

Merge (outer/cartesian) with a frame of `x*`:

```r
alldat <- merge(data.frame(x1=c(1,1,2),x2=c(1,2,2),ign=1), dat, by="ign")
subset(alldat, (!is.na(y1B) | x1 > 1) & (!is.na(y2B) | x2 > 1), select = -ign)
#    x1 x2 y1A y1B y1C y2A y2B y2C
# 5   1  1  NA   1  NA  NA   1  NA
# 13  1  2  NA   1  NA   1  NA  NA
# 14  1  2  NA   1  NA  NA   1  NA
# 15  1  2  NA   1  NA  NA  NA   1
# 19  2  2   1  NA  NA   1  NA  NA
# 20  2  2   1  NA  NA  NA   1  NA
# 21  2  2   1  NA  NA  NA  NA   1
# 22  2  2  NA   1  NA   1  NA  NA
# 23  2  2  NA   1  NA  NA   1  NA
# 24  2  2  NA   1  NA  NA  NA   1
# 25  2  2  NA  NA   1   1  NA  NA
# 26  2  2  NA  NA   1  NA   1  NA
# 27  2  2  NA  NA   1  NA  NA   1
```

The `ign` column is merely to force/enable `merge` to do a cartesian/outer join.